# fadeIn fadeOut element when hovering another, not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="mask"></div>
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href"#"></a></li
        <li><a href"#"></a></li
        <li><a href"#"></a></li
    </ul>
</div
```

And CSS:

```
#mask {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:130;
    background-color:rgba(10,10,10, 0.6);
    display: none;
}
```

I want #mask to appear with fade on #menu hover and I do this with following jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
     $('#menu').hover(over, out);
   });

   function over(event)
   {
     $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);
     $('#mask').css("display","block");
   }
   function out(event)
   {
     $('#mask').fadeOut(1000);
   }
 </script>
```

It works ok, but the problem is, if the mouse is moving in and out of #menu many times before the timeout of 1sec expires, then the #mask keeps fade in and out for as many times the mouse has been moved over and out of the menu...i need something in the code to stop triggering hover action for 1sec after the first trigger.

I hope you understood what i mean.

Thank you.

---

SOLVED, working a bit on Craig Riter`s idea with .stop() method.
added one line before .fadeIn

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#menu-eng').hover(over, out);
});
function over(event)
{      
$('#mask').stop("opacity","0.9");       
$('#mask').fadeIn(1000);
$('#mask').css("display","block");
}
function out(event)
{      
$('#mask').fadeOut(1000);
}
</script>
```

Comment: a link to a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/ would be very helpfull

Comment: You could unbind the event and rebind when it's finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the jQuery animations are queuing up and continue to execute.  You should look at trying to use the `.stop()` method before doing the `.fadeIn()` so that the you can terminate the old animation.

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: Thank you, adding .stop() before .fadeIn solves this problem but creates another one, next time i hover #menu the #mask is loaded with  less opacity, and finally is invissible, i need to reload page for the fadeIn to work again, your solution is close but needs something more...

Comment: SOLVED!!! working a bit on your idea with .stop, i added "opacity","0.6" and so the mask returns always with the correct opacity, the code is this:

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $('#menu-eng').hover(over, out);
   });
   function over(event)
   {      
    $('#mask').stop("opacity","0.9");      
$('#mask').fadeIn(1000);
     $('#mask').css("display","block");
   }
   function out(event)
   {      
    $('#mask').fadeOut(1000);
   }
   </script>

Answer (score 1):

Before performing the `fadeIn` or `fadeOut` check if the `#mask` is currently being [animated](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/).

```
    function over(event)
    {
        if(!$("#mask").is(":animated")){
         $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);
         $('#mask').css("display","block");
        }
    }

    function out(event)
    {
       if(!$("#mask").is(":animated")){
         $('#mask').fadeOut(1000);
       }
    }
```

**JS Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/nMN62/

Comment: @Gasli Taking a look at it now, its because the mask displays over the menu.

Comment: @Gasli If you adjust the `z-index` and `position` of the elements it works. See: http://jsfiddle.net/nMN62/

Comment: I'm not sure that checking for `:animated` in the `out()` function is a good plan, because if the user moves the mouse out while the element is still fading in it won't fade out again unless the mouse is moved in and out a second time.

Comment: Yes, it works but with the problems that nnnnn says, plus sometimes the mask stays always visible even the mouse is out of  #menu.

Answer (score 0):

Just stop the current animation by using `.stop()` for preventing this issue. Code is given below.

```
$("#mask").hover(function(){ 
    $(this).stop(true, true).fadeOut(100)
}, function(){
       $(this).stop(true, true).fadeIn(50)
});
```